# Вложенный-запрос SQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы Users и Games . Users содержит id, first _name,  last_name, email. Games содержит id, first_player_id,  second_player_id . Нужно выбрать с помощью вложенного запроса все имена и email first_player_id

Comment: Выбирайте. Кто вам мешает это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы вам не объединить таблицы с join???

```
select
  Users.id,
  Users.first_name,
  Users.last_name,
  Users.email 
from Users join 
  Games on Users.id = Games.first_player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Вложенный подзапрос можно делать следующим образом

```
select first_name, last_name, email from Users where id in (select first_player_id from Games)
```